# HTTP API: CRUD many relations of a collection

Tags: api, http, rest, many-to-many

I'm looking for a convention for applying CRUD operations to collections of relations  (where the each relation has no metadata).

In the following scenario, I already have basic CRUD operations for 'alphas' and 'betas'. The first of each PUT/GET/HEAD/DELETE pair comprise fairly straightforward CRUD for relations between specific 'alphas' and 'betas'. I'd like to extend this pattern to manage large sets of relations with minimal chatter.

- `PUT /alphas/{alpha_id}/betas/{beta_id}`

  Create a relation between an alpha and a beta
- `PUT /alphas/{alpha_id}/betas?attribute={value}`

  **Create relations between an alpha and *all* betas with an arbitrary attribute-value**
- `GET /alphas/{alpha_id}/betas`

  List a collection of beta objects with a relation to an alpha
- `GET /alphas/{alpha_id}/betas?attribute={value}`

  List a collection of beta objects with a relation to an alpha where beta.attribute=value
- `HEAD /alphas/{alpha_id}/betas/{beta_id}`

  Check for a relation between an alpha and a beta
- `HEAD /alphas/{alpha_id}/betas?attribute={value}`

  Check for at least one relation between an alpha and a beta with an arbitrary attribute-value pair
- `DELETE /alphas/{alpha_id}/betas/{beta_id}`

  Delete a relations between an alpha and a beta
- `DELETE /alphas/{alpha_id}/betas?attribute={value}`

  Delete all relations between an alpha and all betas with an arbitrary attribute=value

My question is specifically about the semantics of the second PUT operation, which look a bit weird to me. It's really operating on the set of ALL betas, not the subset of betas with an *existing* relation to an alpha, as seen in GET/HEAD/DELETE... is there a better way to express this PUT operation? Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up settling on a two part call, starting with retrieving a collection of the desired betas:

```
GET /alphas/{alpha_id}/betas?attribute={value}
```

... and then POSTing a list of `beta_id`s to:

```
POST /alphas/{alpha_id}/betas
```